# in CSS content div overlapping with footer

Tags: css, css-float

The 'page' div has three divs. 'headerdiv', 'contentall' and 'footerdiv'. The 'contentall' and 'footerdiv' are overlapping.

Even if i add 'top: 100px' to 'footerdiv' it still does not help.
Please help.

I am new to the forum and wasn't able to post the css code (still need to learn how code is posted here).

Sample page with problem: http://spdyt.com/yahoo-seo/

I checked out such previous discussions but wasn't able to figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Could you add to your question a sample that contains just the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the 'contentall' is floated or contains floated elements, that would cause the div to loose its height.

Possible solutions:

1. `Add 'clear:both' to 'footerdiv'` *=> Not recommended. the 'contentall' still doesn't have height)*
2. `Add an empty div just before you close 'contentall' and add 'clear:both' to that new div` *=> Not recommended. makes a mess of your code)*
3. `Add class 'clearfix' to the 'contentall' div` *=> but before doing so you need to implement the clearfix class => http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html | Recommended*

I hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not your footer, the problems the content. If you only delete `position:relative;` you can see it. unforutnately then the header overlapses the content because its not cleared correctly. I suggest to add an empty `clear:both;`   to the headerdiv. It's just cleaner than using you breadcrumbs div.

Make it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="headerdiv">
     <div id="mastheaddiv">
     <div id="headext">
     <div id="breadnsearch">
     <div style="clear:both;height:1px;width:100%;"></div>
</div>
<div id="contentall"></div>
<div id="footerdiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#mastheaddiv {
    float: left;
    width: 79%;
}


#headext {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 9px;
    width: 20%;
}


#breadnsearch {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#contentall {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just an advice: First of all I suggest always to define a width and a height of a div. In my experience you'll have less problems simlar to this.